# Enterprise Pattern and Practise: configure Sql Azure transient fault Configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, enterprise-library, azure-sql-database

I am trying to implement SQL Azure Transient Fault Configuration in my ASP.NET application. I am trying to following: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680899(v=pandp.50).aspx

Though I didn't find the block on how can I configure this in config file. I am getting `The type RetryManager does not have an accessible constructor.` error in my code. I read in some forum that I should configure it using config file, but how is my question. Thanks.

**EDIT**: I am using Enterprise Lib 5.0

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="RetryPolicyConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling.Configuration.RetryPolicyConfigurationSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling, Version=5.1.1209.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    <section name="typeRegistrationProvidersConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.TypeRegistrationProvidersConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </configSections>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <RetryPolicyConfiguration defaultRetryStrategy="Incremental Retry Strategy" defaultSqlConnectionRetryStrategy="Backoff Retry Strategy" defaultSqlCommandRetryStrategy="Incremental Retry Strategy" defaultAzureStorageRetryStrategy="Incremental Retry Strategy" defaultAzureServiceBusRetryStrategy="Fixed Interval Retry Strategy">
    <incremental name="Incremental Retry Strategy" retryIncrement="00:00:05" maxRetryCount="5" />
    <fixedInterval name="Fixed Interval Retry Strategy" retryInterval="00:00:01" maxRetryCount="10" />
    <exponentialBackoff name="Backoff Retry Strategy" minBackoff="00:00:01" maxBackoff="00:00:30" deltaBackoff="00:00:10" maxRetryCount="10" />
  </RetryPolicyConfiguration>
  <typeRegistrationProvidersConfiguration>
    <clear />
    <add name="Caching" sectionName="cachingConfiguration" />
    <add name="Cryptography" sectionName="securityCryptographyConfiguration" />
    <add name="Exception Handling" sectionName="exceptionHandling" />
    <add name="Instrumentation" sectionName="instrumentationConfiguration" />
    <add name="Logging" sectionName="loggingConfiguration" />
    <add name="Policy Injection" sectionName="policyInjection" />
    <add name="Security" sectionName="securityConfiguration" />
    <add name="Data Access" providerType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSyntheticConfigSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data" />
    <add name="Validation" providerType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Configuration.ValidationTypeRegistrationProvider, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation" />
    <add sectionName="RetryPolicyConfiguration" name="RetryPolicyConfiguration" />
  </typeRegistrationProvidersConfiguration>
  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```